# How does the isolate scope "@" work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was messing around with the Angular documentation on directives and expected this to work:

I figured I would be able to grab the info attribute using "@" but it doesn't seem to work, I'm expecting info.name and info.address expressions to be displayed, but they are blank.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example16-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="docsIsolateScopeDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
  <my-customer info="naomi"></my-customer>
  <hr>
  <my-customer info="igor"></my-customer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsIsolateScopeDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.naomi = { name: 'Naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
    $scope.igor = { name: 'Igor', address: '123 Somewhere' };
  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        info: '@'
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-customer-iso.html'
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

my-customer-iso.html

```
Name: {{info.name}} Address: {{info.address}}
```

Comment: *"it doesn't seem to work"* doesn't explain what it actually is doing or what you expect it to do.

Comment: seems like a misinterpretation of the docs. Inspect what that scope value really is in browser dev tools

Comment: If you are going to pass an object into the directive, you would want to use the binding operator, "=".

Comment: ah i see, @ seems to always expect a string, or convert the thing you assigned into a string

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much, 'Isolate Scope' means that a child scope is created specifically for the directive, at the simplest.  The scope itself is a fundamentally different one than the scope that the current controller is operating on.

I also had issues with Isolate Scope.  This [article/tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope) helped me a great deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that @ seems to always expect a string, or convert the attribute you assigned into a string, so info.name won't render because there is no .name property on a string "naomi"